# How do I instantiate IDictionary in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I need to instantiate IDictionary object in powershell but can not figure out what the proper syntax shall be.

```
Import-module docker
$config = [Docker.DotNet.Models.Config]::new()
$dict = new-object 'system.collections.generic.dictionary[string,string]' 
$dict.Add("d:\container\content", "c:\inetpub\wwwrooot\content")
$config.Volumes = $dict

Exception setting "Volumes": "Cannot convert the "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]" value of type "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]" to type "System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]"."
At D:\docker\run-MFEcountainer.ps1:6 char:1
+ $config.Volumes = $dict
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message tells you that it's expecting a different type than the one you are passing.

It looks like you should be doing this:

```
$dict = new-object 'system.collections.generic.dictionary[string,object]'
```